# HtmlAgility Html Node is not showing up in the correct order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I've been playing around with HTMLAgility but to no avail, the structure of the HTML is not showing up correctly.

Here is the HTML I am trying to read (simplified)

`<table>...</table>`

As you can see its missing `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Here is the code I have so far:

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str_html));

//check if <html> exists. If not create <html>
var htmlNode = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html");
if (htmlNode == null)
{
    htmlNode = html.CreateElement("html");
    var htmlCollection = html.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
    htmlNode.AppendChildren(htmlCollection);
    html.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
    html.DocumentNode.PrependChild(htmlNode);
}

//check if <head> exists, if not create <head>
HtmlNode head = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
HtmlNode cssLink = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//link[contains(@href, '/assets/global/css/reset.css')]");
if (head != null)
{
    //if <link> does not exist, create <link> to reset.css
    if (cssLink == null)
    {
        cssLink = html.CreateElement("link");
        cssLink.SetAttributeValue("rel", "stylesheet");
        cssLink.SetAttributeValue("href", Url.Content("/assets/global/css/reset.css"));
        head.AppendChild(cssLink);
    }
}
else
{
    //
    var htmlNode2 = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html");
    head = html.CreateElement("head");
    var htmlCollection = html.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
    html.DocumentNode.InnerHtml(head);

    if (cssLink == null)
    {
        cssLink = html.CreateElement("link");
        cssLink.SetAttributeValue("rel", "stylesheet");
        cssLink.SetAttributeValue("href", Url.Content("/assets/global/css/reset.css"));
        head.AppendChild(cssLink);
    }
}

//check if <body> exists, if yes, add style='margin:0; padding:0'
HtmlNode htmlBody = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
if (htmlBody != null)
    htmlBody.SetAttributeValue("style", "margin: 0; padding: 0;");

//remove <script> and <iframe> references
html.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "iframe")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(n => n.Remove());

str_html = html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Here is the output:

`<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/global/css/reset.css"></head><html><table>...</table</html>`

Why is HEAD showing in front of `<html>`. I have tried .appendchild as well. but it produced the following:

`<html><table>asome stuff </table></html><head></html><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/global/css/reset.css">`

I need the code to appear as so:

`<html><head>some stuff</head><body></body></html>`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. It's missing the output and a at least one more thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to prepend `<head>` as child of `<html>`, for example (non relevant codes removed for clarity) :

```
var str_html = "<table>...</table>";
.....
if (head != null)
{
    .....
}
else
{
    head = html.CreateElement("head");
    var htmlCollection = html.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
    htmlNode.PrependChild(head); //I only added this line to your existing code

    if (cssLink == null)
    {
        cssLink = html.CreateElement("link");
        cssLink.SetAttributeValue("rel", "stylesheet");
        cssLink.SetAttributeValue("href", Url.Content("/assets/global/css/reset.css"));
        head.AppendChild(cssLink);
    }
}
```

And the output is in correct order :

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/global/css/reset.css"></head><table>...</table></html>
```

Comment: Wow... I am such a dingdong. Yes that fixed it. Thank you so much!